# Fade & swap images with opacity & setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to swap out a main image when when a user hovers over a thumbnail of said image (like a gallery.) I need to use `set` & `clearInterval` whilst editing the DOM. All this with vanilla JavaScript. The issue I have here is that:

- The hovered image fades out, but not in.
- The swap & fade effect gets accelerated with each hover.

I know that `set` & `clearInterval` has something to do with this, but I can't get it to work properly.

```
const MAINIMG = document.getElementById("mainImage");
let imgSrc;

function swapImg(e) {
    MAINIMG.style.opacity = 1;
    imgSrc = e.target.src;

    if (MAINIMG.currentSrc != e.target.currentSrc) {
        fadeImg();    
    } 
}

function fadeImg() {
    timer = setInterval(opacity, 100);
}

function opacity(src) {

    if (MAINIMG.style.opacity >= 0.5) {
        MAINIMG.style.opacity = MAINIMG.style.opacity - 0.1;

    } else if (MAINIMG.style.opacity == 0.4) {
        MAINIMG.src = imgSrc;
        MAINIMG.style.opacity = MAINIMG.style.opacity + 0.1;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

document.getElementById("imgOne").addEventListener("mouseover", swapImg);
document.getElementById("imgTwo").addEventListener("mouseover", swapImg);
```

HTML

```
<img id="mainImage" src="../images/imgOne.jpg" alt="" width="200" />

<div id="galleryImages">
   <img src="../images/imgOne.jpg" height="111.35" id="imgOne"/>
   <img src="../images/imgTwo.jpg" width="80" id="imgTwo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML that comes with the JavaScript and create a minimal reproducible example to experience the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edited answer

The `style.opacity` value has a funny behavior to it. When it has a value above 0 it is an integer, but when it reaches 0 it becomes a string. So when doing `MAINIMG.style.opacity = MAINIMG.style.opacity + 0.1;` you are actually adding `0.1` to `"0"`.

You can tackle this by parsing the opacity value to a floating point number and then add the 0.1 to it. Check the example below.

```
MAINIMG.style.opacity = parseFloat(MAINIMG.style.opacity) + 0.1;
```

## Original answer

CSS is really good in handling transitions and will save you a lot of trouble calculating the opacity of an element. So if you can try to use it.

Down here I've made an example of what you could do to make it work using a combination of Vanilla JavaScript and CSS.

The `swapImg` function gets the `src` of the hovered image, just like in your own example, and checks if the `MAINIMG.src` is different from the hovered image. If it is not it will add a class to the `MAINIMG` called `fade`. This class sets the opacity of the image to `0`. The duration of the opacity transition is set in the `MAINIMG.style.transitionDuration = TRANSITION_SPEED + 'ms';` line. You can modify this value if you want to your liking.

**After** the transition is complete the `MAINIMG` will be invisible. Then the `setTimeout` kicks in, changes the `src` of the `MAINIMG` and removes the `fade` class so the image will appear again.

I hope this is what you are looking for.
If you have any questions let me know.

```js
const MAINIMG = document.getElementById("mainImage");
const GALLERYIMAGES = document.getElementById("galleryImages");
const TRANSITION_SPEED = 250;

MAINIMG.style.transitionDuration = TRANSITION_SPEED + 'ms';

function swapImg(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    const newSrc = e.target.src;
    if (newSrc !== MAINIMG.src) {
      MAINIMG.classList.add('fade');
      setTimeout(function() {
        MAINIMG.src = newSrc;
        MAINIMG.classList.remove('fade');
      }, TRANSITION_SPEED);
    }
  }
}

GALLERYIMAGES.addEventListener('mouseover', swapImg);
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
}

#mainImage {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#mainImage.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

#galleryImages img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="mainImage" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/201x200" alt="" width="200" />

<div id="galleryImages">
   <img class="galleryHover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/201x200"/>
   <img class="galleryHover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x201"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and answering but the issue here is that I need to use set & clearIntervals. That is what I can't get to work properly.